# Usar arquivo .php no lugar de .js

Tags: php, javascript

Quero usar um arquivo externo `.js` (JavaScript) em meu projeto mas gostaria de usar códigos PHP para manipular o JavaScript dentro do `.js`. Sei que a extensão `.js` irá tratar o arquivo como JavaScript e se eu inserir `<?php ... ?>` irá resultar em erro pois isso não faz parte da sintaxe JavaScript.

> Usando o código JavaScript na mesma página `.php` com `script` é fácil
>   pois basta mesclar códigos PHP com JavaScript para alterar o código.
>   Ex.:
>
> ```
> <script>
> var string = "<?=$variável?>";
> </script>
> ```

Mas simulando um `.js` externo via PHP, é possível chamar:

```
<script src="pagina.php"></script>
```

E tratar essa página `pagina.php` como se fosse um arquivo `.js` para que eu possa usar códigos PHP (conectar a banco de dados etc.) para fazer o que desejo e retornar apenas códigos JavaScript manipulado pelo PHP?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

É possível fazer isso, mas com o PHP você necessita informar que a resposta HTTP que você retornará será um código JS para que o cliente (navegador) possa interpretar da forma correta. Na verdade, a extensão do arquivo pouco importa, ela é apenas uma extensão do nome do arquivo para auxiliar os usuários e algumas partes do sistema operacional, de forma que não precise ler os metadados do arquivo para obter seu tipo. Neste caso, acredito que os servidores web são previamente configurados para enviar na resposta o cabeçalho referente ao tipo de arquivo com base em sua extensão, então somente escrever o código JS em um arquivo com extensão PHP pode não funcionar em alguns casos, por isso a necessidade de informar corretamente o cabeçalho.

Isso se dá através do cabeçalho `Content-Type`.

```
Content-Type: application/javascript
```

Assim, basta você escrever, por exemplo:

```
<?php

// script.php

header('Content-Type: application/javascript');

echo "console.log('Olá mundo')";
```

E chamar o arquivo:

```
<script src="script.php"></script>
```

Que a mensagem será exibida no console, visto que será uma resposta HTTP de JavaScript válida - algo parecido com:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/javascript
Content-Length: 24

console.log('Olá mundo')
```

Que seria a mesma resposta gerada pelo servidor web para um arquivo estático JS com esse mesmo conteúdo.

**Nota:** Vale lembrar que isso não é, conceitualmente, *escrever JS com PHP*, é apenas escrever um texto que, por ventura, será interpretado como código JS no cliente. Para o PHP, não faz diferença, sempre será texto. Rigorosamente falando, você só estará gerando um texto formatado que pode ser analisado como JS.

Comment: @dvd para garantir o funcionamento, sim. É necessário lembrar que o navegador é apenas mais um de tantos clientes que consomem a página. Funcionar sem o cabeçalho é provavelmente devido ao navegador sempre tentar analisar a resposta na tag `<script>` como JS, mas que não seja garantido que bots façam o mesmo ou um cliente cURL. Adicionar o cabeçalho é não deixar brechas.

Comment: Entendi... eu vi a atualização da resposta explicando, por isso removi o comentário. Obg novamente pela excelente resposta. Abs!